# How to create a TypeGuard to ensure value not None in python?

Tags: python, python-typing

Given the following code

```py
val = object.data
assert val, 'data should not be None'
```

It use a lot in my project to ensure `Optional[T]` data type is not None.

I create the following method to make the code DRY.

```py
def not_none(val: T, msg: str) -> AssertTypeOrSomething[T]:
  assert val, msg
  return val
```

It works in runtime, but how to make the right type annotation to pass the static check?

Comment: Why not use `Optional[T]` instead of `T` as the passed type?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on `assert` to control the flow of program at normal runtime - assertions are removed if optimized compilation is requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as requested, you can set up the typing like this:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def not_none(val: T | None, msg: str) -> T:
  assert val is not None, msg # use `is not None` in case `T` is a `bool`
  return val
```

It's worth noting that you should only use this method for debugging or when *you* know it is *impossible* for the value to be `None`, but the *type checker* does not know. Assertions are ignored when you run your code in optimized-mode (with the `-O` flag).

If you want to control flow of code, use a traditional `raise`:

```py
def not_none(val: T | None, msg: str) -> T:
  if val is None:
    raise TypeError(msg)

  return val
```

Most (all?) mainstream type checkers support type refinement, so the `not_none` method is not even required:

```py
x: int | None

x += 1 # type error: can't add `1` to None
assert x is not None
x += 1 # no type error, checker knows that `x` cannot be None anymore
```